# Only allow certain characters

Tags: python

I have a Discord bot made in Python that looks up usernames. Usernames can only be A-z and 0-9.
How can I stop people from making queries with special symbols?

Disallowed example:

```
robotic@934!@
```

Allowed example:

```
Anf
GGDFG94
```

Since people can look up any name, it would only be beneficial to only allow certain characters and not full words/part of words.

```
whitelist = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']

if SOMETHINGTOCOMPARE in whitelist:
    print("You are allowed to look this username up.")
else:
    print("Your username contains special characters. Disallowed.")
```

I am storing the username in "response" string

Comment: Welcome to SO.  First simple thing that comes to mind is to loop through the username and check if each character is in the whitelist.

Comment: @ewong are you able to give me example in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if `SOMETHINGTOCOMPARE` is a subset of `whitelist` ([set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set)):

```
def check(SOMETHINGTOCOMPARE):
    whitelist = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']

    # Test whether every element in SOMETHINGTOCOMPARE is in whitelist.
    if set(SOMETHINGTOCOMPARE) <= set(whitelist):
        return True
    return False
```

You can test the function with:

```
if check('robotic@934!@'):
    print("You are allowed to look this username up.")
else:
    print("Your username contains special characters. Disallowed.")

if check('Anf'):
    print("You are allowed to look this username up.")
else:
    print("Your username contains special characters. Disallowed.")

if check('GGDFG94'):
    print("You are allowed to look this username up.")
else:
    print("Your username contains special characters. Disallowed.")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to allow letters and digits then all you need is the `str.isalnum` method ("alnum" stands for "alphanumeric"):

```py
if SOMETHINGTOCOMPARE.isalnum():
    ...
```

Otherwise there is a couple of options in the other answers. Personally I would use `all`:

```py
from string import digits, ascii_letters

whitelist = set(digits + ascii_letters + "#_-[]")

if all(c in whitelist for c in SOMETHINGTOCOMPARE):
    ...
```

Comment: Ah yes, it's already in the library. As long as your rules exactly conform to this function, you should use it.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum

Comment: This would be the ideal solution, but the symbols: [ _ ] - and # are also allowed. I just did not mention it to make it easier for you guys to understand

Comment: Too bad it can't be so simple ;-) I've updated the answer with an alternative solution that should work for you.

Comment: Thank you very much @Czaporka ,your solution worked perfectly.

Comment: Great to hear that. If the problem is solved, it would be nice if you could mark one of the answers as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

You just want to check for characters that are in one collection, and not in other collection, so fundamentally, you should be looking at set operations.

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

```
import string

def acceptable(querystring):
    acceptable = set(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
    guess = set(querystring)
    disallowed_characters_in_guess = guess - acceptable
    return not bool(disallowed_characters_in_guess)
    
if acceptable("robotic@934!@"):
    raise ValueError

if not acceptable("robotic934"):
    raise ValueError

print ("okay")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def checkifallowed(string):
    whitelist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
                 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
    for i in string:
        if i not in whitelist:
            return False
    return True


somethingtocompare = input('What is the username that you want to look up?')
if checkifallowed(somethingtocompare):
    print('You can search this name up')
else:
    print('Disallowed.')
```

This just defines a function that checks in all the characters are in the whitelist, and returns True or False. The following code just asks for an input and returns the result.

Answer (score 0):

use a regular expression to find pattern matches

```
pattern= r"^[a-z,A-Z,0-9\s]+$"

myval="robotic@934"

#cons,args=re.search(pattern,input).groups()
all_matches=re.findall(pattern, myval)
print(all_matches)
```

output:
[]